# Why does a superclass implement interface methods which are supposed to be implemented by the child?

Tags: java, interface

Here is a parent class

```
public class Parent {
    public void f() {

    }
}
```

Here is a simple interface

```
public interface If {
    public void f();
}
```

Here is a child class

```
public class Child extends Parent implements If{}
```

My question is:
 Although it is `Child` which claims to implement the interface `If`, the interface method is implemented in `Parent`. Why is this allowed?

Comment: Because you are free to name the methods you write as you want. It doesn´t implement the interface it simply has a method called `f`

Comment: That’s a strange question. Why should we forbid this?

Comment: "the interface method is implemented in Parent. " - no, that's not happening here.

Comment: `Parent` does not implement _any_ interface.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why is this allowed?

Because `Child` satisfies the contract. The contract `Child` makes, by implementing `If`, is that it will provide a public `f` function that accepts no arguments and has no return value. It does that. *How* it does it, in this case by inheriting it from a superclass, is irrelevant. The contract is satisfied, which is all that matters.

> the interface method is implemented in Parent

Not really, it just happens to have the `f` method. If you did `If inst = new Parent()` you'd get get a compilation error, because `Parent` doesn't say it implements `If` (there's no `implements If` on it); implementing `If` isn't part of its contract. `Child`, on the other hand, *does* provide that contract, and so `If inst = new Child()` works just fine.

FWIW, you probably wouldn't do this *on purpose*, although there's arguably nothing wrong with it. But it could come up if it just happened that the superclass you want to use has a perfect fit for one of the methods in the interface you want to implement.

When that happens, you have three choices:

1. Do nothing and let `Parent`'s method directly implement the interface method.
2. Override `Parent`'s method even though you're not going to do anything differently, e.g.:

   ```
   @Override
   public void f() {
       super.f();
   }
   ```

   ...which really doesn't accomplish anything unless you have code you want to run prior to or after calling `Parent`'s `f`.
3. Override `f` and implement it yourself, ignoring `Parent`'s version. But that only makes sense if `Parent`'s `f` does something *completely different* from the interface method's `f` — in which case, you shouldn't be subclassing `Parent` in the first place, because if you reimplement `f` in terms of the interface's behavior, your `f` won't satisfy the `Parent#f` contract anymore (in terms of its behavior) and you'll break the "is a" rule for subclassing.

So really, option 1 is perfectly reasonable if it happens organically. You just probably wouldn't set it up on purpose.

Comment: Just to add that this approach is logically not really correct - if later on someone changes implementation of `Parent` and removes the method `f` from there (or changes its signature, whatever), the `Child` stops being valid.

Comment: @Sva.Mu: `Child` is already tightly-bound to `Parent`, it's the nature of subclassing. The number of ways changes to `Parent` can affect `Child` is legion.

Comment: I don't say it is not, rather tried to point out that it is `Child` that makes commitment against the interface, not `Parent`, thus it is more logical to implement the interface method(s) directly in `Child` as there is nothing that would force `Parent` to "keep it".

Comment: @Sva.Mu: But remember that `Child` also has an "is a" commitment with regard to `Parent`. I've added to the answer on this. I don't think this situation ever came up for me in my Java programming, it was interesting to think through the options.

Answer (score 2):

It is completely legal because when you implement the method, it works for both.

From class perspective and from interface perspective. A single implementation would serve the both purpose and there is no point of ambiguity it.

There is no way to restrict  a Class or Interface to having same method signature, unless you have a relationship with them, but in this case there will be no problems.

Answer (score 0):

The main point of an interface is to list a set of methods, which could be called on any object of a class implementing the interface.

By declaring that a class implements an interface you declare that this set of methods can be called on your class.

As soon as this is the case (e.g. in your example), there is no problem.